# How to continue serving requests in Java Servlet container while load balancer removes the server from the pool based on a health check?

Tags: servlets, load-balancing, servletcontextlistener, servlet-container

I want to continue serving requests while my load balancer removes the server from the pool based on a health check. If I know the server is being shut down, I can change the health check to unhealthy and give it time to be removed without dropping any requests.

**My attempt: `contextDestroyed` in `ServletContextListener`**

I'm delaying shutdown of my web app like this in a [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html):

```
  override def contextDestroyed(sce: ServletContextEvent) {
    logger.info(s"contextDestroyed, suspend for $ShutdownDelayMS ms")
    Thread.sleep(ShutdownDelayMS)
    logger.info("Suspend finished, shutting down")

  }
```

I see the logs and the delay in between, but as soon as [`contextDestroyed`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html#contextDestroyed-javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent-) is called, the server will no longer serve requests, and in stdout I immediately see:

```
[INFO] Stopped ServerConnector@19877453{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
```

Am I misunderstanding how `contextDestroyed` is supposed to work? Jetty 9.2.9.v20150224, javax.servlet 3.0.1.

Docs for `contextDestroyed` say:

> Receives notification that the ServletContext is about to be shut
>   down. All servlets and filters will have been destroyed before any
>   ServletContextListeners are notified of context destruction.

So that means it immediately stops serving requests if I'm reading it correctly. Is there another way to achieve what I'm trying to do, create a delay that allows requests to continue being served?

Comment: You might get a better response if you explained the underlying motive of your Question. Your Question itself explains that by definition `contextDestroyed` is the wrong place to expect requests to continue being served. Why are you trying to do a delayed shutdown? What is your goal or purpose?

Comment: You should post clarifications as edits to your Question rather than as comments.

Comment: @BasilBourque done